# Is Sharepoint 2003/MOSS 2007 able to return a document snippet containing search terms?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, full-text-search

Is there a search API for getting a short text containing the search terms so that I can use to display to users?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? Do you mean that you want some kind of online help that will display what syntax a user could use in the search box? Or do you want something that returns the search terms used in the current/active search?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I made. I actually want the latter - something that returns search terms used in the current search. For example my Sharepoint has indexed a document, which has a sentence "I find that stackoverflow rocks" and some other sentences. When a user searches for "stackoverflow", I want to return the link of the document, together with that sentence, so that user can get an idea of if that's what he/she wants before clicking the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's properties that can be returned from a search - HitHighlightedSummary & HitHighlightedFields.

If you're building a search in code you can request these in the same way as other fields - they should contain what you're after.

If you take a look at the configuration for the standard results web part, you can see there's an XML property which is the fields requested which includes these by default.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but you could traverse through all managed and / or crawled properties? for more information look here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428648.aspx)

Examples from the referenced page:

**Managed Properties:**

```
Schema schema = new Schema(this.searchContext);
foreach (ManagedProperty prop in schema.AllManagedProperties)
{
  TreeNode node = treeViewManagedProperties.Nodes.Add(prop.Name);
  node.Tag = prop;
  foreach (Mapping mapping in prop.GetMappings())
  {
   node.Nodes.Add(mapping.CrawledPropertyName);
  }
}
```

**Crawled Properties**

```
Schema schema = new Schema(this.searchContext);
foreach (CrawledProperty cprop in schema.QueryCrawledProperties(string.Empty, 1000, Guid.NewGuid(), string.Empty, true))
{
  listBoxCrawledProperties.Items.Add(cprop);
}
```

**EDIT: This is for MOSS BTW**